# How to execute two jquery events at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I execute two event at same time ? I do as following way. But it doesn't work properly. If I execute single at once, both work fine.

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
          $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown('slow');
    else
    // these two events
        $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).parent().find('ul').hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: Those aren't event.  Those are function calls.  And you didn't surround them with `{}` if you want those last two statements to only happen for the else.  Without `{}` after an if/else, only the next immediate statement will execute.

Comment: You're missing brackets surrounding your two "events" that are not events :)

Comment: But still last line of code will be executed always.

Comment: @Taplar @Bertrand, I am still learning `jquery`, so new in term, got that difference between function and event. Now it works after adding `{}` . But It was still working though `{}` is missed for single line.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery issue.  This is a javascript syntax issue.  When you write an if/else, it will only execute the next immediate statement after it. `if(conditional) <statement> else <statement>`.  A statement is one single chain of commands.  If you want to execute multiple statements as part of a conditional, you have to put them in `{}`.  This makes them a statement block and is treated by the conditional as a single statement.